# BEGINNER - coding date of birth in SAS

Tags: sas, new-operator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1hQt.png)I'm new to SAS coding in a beginning class and I'm struggling with the basics. I'm trying to first create a date_of_birth variable but I keep getting that month_of_birth, day_of_birth, and year_of_birth is uninitialized. I've put the code below, any help would be appreciated!

```
code:



data dob;
set Assign6_sp2022;
date_of_birth = MDY (Month_of_Birth, Day_of_Birth, Year_of_Birth);
run;

log:
48   data dob;
49   set Assign6_sp2022;
50   date_of_birth = MDY (Month_of_Birth, Day_of_Birth, Year_of_Birth);
51   run;

NOTE: Variable Month_of_Birth is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable Day_of_Birth is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable Year_of_Birth is uninitialized.
NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.
      Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column).
      1 at 50:17
NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.ASSIGN6_SP2022.
NOTE: The data set WORK.DOB has 1 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: Hi Lauren, welcome to Stack Overflow.  What variables are on ASSIGN6_SP2022?  MDY creates a date from 3 other integer variables or values.  Can you post a PROC CONTENTS or an example of what variables/values are on the dataset ASSIGN6_SP2022?  Thanks!

Comment: The notes indicate that those three variables are not in that dataset.  They also indicate that there is at least one other variable that is in that dataset that is not mentioned in your code since the resulting dataset has 5 variables and your code only mentions four variables.

Comment: Does that picture show the variable LABELS or the variable NAMES?  In VIEWTABLE under the View menu you have the choice to see COLUMN NAME or COLUMN LABEL.  It is the NAME that you need to use in the SAS code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your table is in the `Assn6` library.
Make sure to use it in the `set` statement : `set Assn6.Assign6_sp2022`.

Also it seems your variables have spaces in their names.
if that is the case, you need to use a quoted string followed by the letter N.
Use `"Month of Birth"n`, `"Day of Birth"n` and  `"Year of Birth"n` instead.

```
data dob;
set Assn6.Assign6_sp2022;
date_of_birth = mdy("Month of Birth"n, "Day of Birth"n, "Year of Birth"n);
run;
```